# How do I know if a view has been drawn

Tags: java, android, android-layout, view

I want to know if its possible to know if a view has been drawn on the screen.

I am not interested in setting a listener and waiting for it, as I already know how to do that. I am looking for a call, to get a true/false on if the view is currently on the screen.

I dont believe I can simply check the visibility as that is a preset variable, regardless of its state, though I could be wrong.

If the view is not draw, I will set a ViewTreeObserver and wait for it, but that is only neccessary if the view has not yet been drawn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since getVisibility() returns a predefined property and u don't want to set a listener; i think the only option is View.isShown().
i hope this helps.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I swear i dug through the methods on view classes last night and couldn't for the life of me find this. But it is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to observe one view, try to create a custom view and override the `draw()` and set a flag in it like:

```
public DemoView extends TextView {
    private boolean mHasDrawn;
    // ...
    @override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.draw(canvas);
        mHasDrawn = true;
    }
}
```

then you can check the `mHasDrawn` to ensure the view has been drawn.
However, I think setting a listener is better than this.